# Excercise 1.75 from Manifolds and Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I came across this exercise *Exercise 1.75 Manifolds and Differential Geometry by Jeffrey M. Lee* which states:

> Let M be a smooth manifold. Let K be a closed subset of M and O an
>   open subset containing K. Show that there exists a smooth function
>   $\beta$ on M that is identically equal to 1 on K, takes values in the
>   interval [0,1], and has compact support in O.

How can this be true? Set $M = \mathbb{R}$ and $K = \mathbb{Z}$ and let O be the union of small balls, one around each integer and none overlapping. How can the support of $\beta$ be compact then? It cant possibly be bounded since it contains $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: He might assume that $M$ or $K$ is compact?

Comment: @JohnMa, Nope, in fact right before he introduces the exercise he says "... we may show that the analogue of Lemma 1.69 works with K closed but not necessarily compact." And what a weird definition if $\mathbb{R}$ does not qualify as a smooth manifold in this text.

Comment: Um, that's weird. Of course one can even take $K = O = M$. The statement can't be correct.

Comment: Oh that's an even better counterexample. I did not find this exercise in the errata either. Maybe time to email professor Lee.